# Derivation of Discharging Current of an Inductor

Tags: current, inductor, discharge

Consider the following circuit:

[image: RL]

When \$t > 0\$, the inductor \$L\$ begins to discharge. I already know from KVL that the sum of voltage drops in the loop containing the inductor is:

\$L\frac{di(t)}{dt} + Ri(t) = 0\$

From this, how could I derive the equation for the discharged current across the inductor i.e. at any time \$t\$:

\$i(t) = I_s e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\$

As I understand, it involves some integration, but I'm a bit stuck so if someone could help derive it for me, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't so much prove it as derive it. This is more a mathematics question. Given a differential equation, come up with the time evolution. However, it's a simple enough one for engineers to do as well. Where do you want to start from, will tables of standard integrals do?

Comment: Thanks or your answer. I only really know the basics of integration/differentiation (i.e. nothing further than differentiating \$2x^2 + 3x + 2\$ and trig functions). I just need someone to go through the mathematical process of deriving it, then I should be able to understand it better.

Comment: @kendalmint24 you'll need to know the derivative and integral of \$e^x\$, too, as well as chain rule of derivation, otherwise this will be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kirchoff's voltage law states that **the algebraic sum of the voltages equals zero for any closed path (loop) in an electrical circuit.** Writing the equation for the voltage loop with the inductor and resistor gives
$$L \frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+Ri_L(t)=0 $$
Dividing with the resistance on both sides gives
$$\frac{L}{R}\frac{di_L(t)}{dt}+i_L(t)=0 $$
The form of this differential equation  indicates that that the solution for \$ i_L(t)\$ must be a function that has the same form as its first derivative. Such a function is an **exponential function**.

We make the guess that the solution is of the form \$i_L(t)=Ke^{st} \$ in which \$ K\$ and \$ s\$ are constants to be determined. Inserting the guess in the actual differential equation gives
$$ \frac{L}{R}Kse^{st}+Ke^{st}=0$$
From this, we see that the equation is true if \$s=-\frac{R}{L} \$

Inserting this value for \$s \$ into \$i_L(t)=Ke^{st} \$ gives
$$i_L(t)=Ke^{\frac{-tR}{L}} $$
Calling \$ \tau=\frac{L}{R} \$ gives
$$i_L(t)=Ke^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} $$

All that's left is to determine \$K \$, and I will leave that to you. Hint: what is \$i_L(0) \$?

Comment: Please consider changing "s" to a different variable, as it is, it is easily confused with the complex frequency as used in the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thankyou! That was extremely helpful

Comment: The polarity you show for the emf across the inductor is wrong. Also, what is the implication of adding a ground connection?

Comment: @Chu I will remove the drawing, as it is not necessary.